# Postgresql: Query to find alarm start and stop timespans

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with a Postgresql (12.7) query that returns one row for each alarm that has been activated (active=true), including start timestamp and stop timestamp (first subsequent row where active=false) for each alarm occurrence and alarm type, like:

| device | start_ts | end_ts | alarm_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154 | 1643663756609 | 1643663937641 | Sound |
| 154 | 1643670929078 | 1643671218920 | Sound |

The source table looks like this:

| device | ts | active | alarm_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154 | 1643663756609 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663786603 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663816604 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663846603 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663876763 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663907643 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663937641 | false | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663967644 | false | Sound |
| 154 | 1643663998604 | false | Sound |
| 154 | 1643670929078 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643670959963 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643670990923 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671022122 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671055641 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671095240 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671126045 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671157080 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671187960 | true | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671218920 | false | Sound |
| 154 | 1643671250040 | false | Sound |

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can do:

```
select
  device,
  min(ts) as start_ts,
  max(next_ts) as end_ts,
  alarm_type
from (
  select *, sum(inc) over(order by ts) as island  
  from (
    select *,
      case when active and not lag(active) over(order by ts) then 1 else 0 end as inc,
      case when active and not lead(active) over(order by ts) then ts end as next_ts
    from t
  ) x
  where active
) y
group by device, island, alarm_type
```